# Python, регулярное выражение для парсинга URL в тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, url

Простейшее регулярное выражение успешно справляется с ссылками в простом тексте:

```
r'(https?://[\S]+)'
```

В нём всё устраивает, но иногда поступает html, где необходимо вычленить ссылку из тэга `a`. Если поступит что-то типа `some text <a href="http://ya.ru">some text`, то в результате вернётся: `http://ya.ru>some`

Вот такое выражение:

```
r'(https?://[\S]+[>$])'
```

возвращает приемлемый результат (ссылку с символом `>` на конце, который потом можно просто обрезать), но уже не обрабатывает ссылки в простом тексте.

Как в Python объединить эти два выражения в одно, по принципу ИЛИ, чтобы получить все совпадения, одно за другим?

Пробовал через `()|()` - так не выходит. Сторонние библиотеки отлично справляются с этой задачей, но надо именно через простейшие регулярные выражения добиться необходимого результата.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое:

```
(https?://[\w.-]+)
```

Но оно будет так-же искать и невалидные ссылки. Например: https://.-ya_.5
Если уверены в валидности своих ссылок в тексте, то вполне рабочий вариант.

Comment: Такой вариант обрезает `https://ya.ru/da.html` до `https://ya.ru` - а надо бы всю ссылку. И % в русских буквах такой вариант скорее всего не воспримет.

Comment: Тогда такой вариант:
`(https?://[^\"\s]+)`

Comment: Это вариант работает как и первый в вопросе. Не обрезает после `>`. А необходимо чтобы обрезал.

Comment: (https?://[^\"\s>]+)

Comment: Да, благодарю, это работает как раз как надо.

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно сработать, попробуй:

```
https?://[\S][^>]+
```

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите ссылки из html достать, то следует использовать html парсер. К примеру, [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import bs4  # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
all_links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
```

В общем случае, [регулярные выражения не подходят для распознавания html](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701166/4279) и даже в тех случаях, когда можно regex использовать [это может быть не самая лучшая опция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/4279).

Comment: Прочитайте внимательнее вопрос. Парсится текст, в котором иногда может оказаться html. Особо обратите внимание на последний абзац.

Comment: @federk: вопросы на Stack Overflow предназначены не только для вас лично. Люди часто пытаются с помощью regex из html вытаскивать информацию без веских на то оснований. Если вы хотите именно regex вытаскивать из текста, который *"иногда может оказаться html"* то нажмите на последнюю ссылку в моём ответе, где показано как с помощью regex html парсить (и сколько усилий требуется в общем случае). Если вы настаиваете именно на regex, то рекомендую явно ограничить типы допустимого ввода текста/uri, явно упомянуть насколько допустимы ошибки (что не все url найдены, или ложные срабатывания).

Comment: @federk в тему [мета-обсуждение](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/4134/23044)